# How to fit a curved surface to a set of data points and obtain the equation for the surface

Tags: python, ros

Ubuntu
ROS Noetic
Python Program

I am attempting to get an equation of a surface that will fit a set of points from point cloud data. The data originates from a lidar scanner. I select a portion of the entire scan in rviz and the coordinates of that selection are obtained [picture of selected surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvHz9.png). The selected surfaces will not always be so linear, as there might be a slight curve in the material. I am some what good at math and programming so any ideas would be great. I mainly program in python. I have the (X,Y,Z) of each of the points, and i also have each value of the coordinates separated by their x, y, and z in arrays (x_array, y_array, z_array, etc.). I will attach my code of my test program in case anyone would want to see how I did things. It is mainly just receiving coordinate data from a ROS topic, going from hexadecimal to float values, and then organizing the floats into various arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from scipy.linalg import lstsq

my_data = 0
array_size = 0
point_size = 0 

def callback(data):
    global my_data
    global array_size
    global point_size
    my_data = data.data
    point_size = data.width
    print("Point Size: ", point_size)
    coord_array_size = (point_size*3)

    i = 1
    current_low = 0
    current_high = 0
    previous_high = 0

    current_hex_string = 0
    hex_string = my_data.hex()

    xyz_points_array = [0]* coord_array_size
    xyz_point_array_counter = 0

    x_point_array = [0]* point_size
    y_point_array = [0]* point_size
    z_point_array = [0]* point_size
    point_array_counter = 0

    while(i <= point_size):
        if(i == 1):
            current_low = 0
            current_high = 32
            previous_high = 32
            i += 1

            current_hex_string = hex_string[current_low:current_high]
            x_coord = x_point_array[point_array_counter] = xyz_points_array[0] = struct.unpack('f', bytes.fromhex(current_hex_string[0:8]))
            y_coord = y_point_array[point_array_counter] = xyz_points_array[1] = struct.unpack('f', bytes.fromhex(current_hex_string[8:16]))
            z_coord = z_point_array[point_array_counter] = xyz_points_array[2] = struct.unpack('f', bytes.fromhex(current_hex_string[16:24]))

            xyz_point_array_counter += 3
            point_array_counter += 1

        elif(i > 1):
            current_low = previous_high
            current_high = (previous_high + 32)
            previous_high = current_high
            i += 1

            current_hex_string = hex_string[current_low:current_high]
            x_coord = x_point_array[point_array_counter] =    xyz_points_array[xyz_point_array_counter] = struct.unpack('f', bytes.fromhex(current_hex_string[0:8]))
            y_coord = y_point_array[point_array_counter] = xyz_points_array[xyz_point_array_counter + 1] = struct.unpack('f', bytes.fromhex(current_hex_string[8:16]))
            z_coord = z_point_array[point_array_counter] = xyz_points_array[xyz_point_array_counter + 2] = struct.unpack('f', bytes.fromhex(current_hex_string[16:24]))

            xyz_point_array_counter += 3
            point_array_counter += 1

    #print("\nCoordinate Array: ", xyz_points_array)
    #print("\nX Coordinate Array: ", x_point_array)
    #print("\nY Coordinate Array: ", y_point_array)
    #print("\nZ Coordinate Array: ", z_point_array)

    #plotting
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(x_point_array, y_point_array, z_point_array, s = 1, c='blue')
    plt.xlabel('X Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
    #plt.zlabel('Z Axis')
    plt.show()


def listener_new():
    rospy.init_node('listener_new', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("rviz_selected_points", PointCloud2, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener_new()
```

Comment: Do you already have an idea of the shape of this surface? Plane? Cylindrical? Etc.?

Comment: The surfaces will vary between linear (flat), almost flat, or slightly curved. They will be rectangular plane selections in general though

Answer (score 2):

For instance, you could use [this very interesting code](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6) to find the quadratic surface fitting your 3D points. I have modified the code to consider only the second order case.

The `C` array consists of the equation coefficients.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some 3-dim points
mean = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
cov = np.array([[1.0,-0.5,0.8], [-0.5,1.1,0.0], [0.8,0.0,1.0]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 50)

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5), np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()


# best-fit quadratic curve
A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,:2], np.prod(data[:,:2], axis=1), data[:,:2]**2]
C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])

# evaluate it on a grid
Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX*YY, XX**2, YY**2], C).reshape(X.shape)

# plot points and fitted surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('auto')
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response of fitting a quadratic surface to 3D points. This is just what I needed, so I appreciate it.

Comment: matplotlib was updated, instead of using gca they said swap it with add_subplot and then it works in newer versions.