# 3D best fitting shape with graphic and equation (Python) (Maybe DSP)

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, signal-processing, multivariate-testing

I need help showing the shape or plane that best fits these coordinates in 3D. I have already found the plane of best fit using least squares method on python. Now I want to see if there is a more exact curve, perhaps one that curves and I want the program to output the equation if possible. I would like to compare these numbers to these z outputs.[The other z outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGlOQ.png)

If it is easier to ask for the relationship between these two z outputs that is something else I would like to know. But I would want the mathematical relationship between the two or how the two planes compare. If you need more information please ask! I have attached code I used already to find the flat plane of best fit.

[This is some of the coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pnjn.png)

```css
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np


'''''
xs=[
      0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
      17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
      24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
      38,39,40,41,42,43,44,
      45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
      52,53,54,55,56,57,58,
      59,60,61,62,63,64,65,
      66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
      73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
      80,81,82,83,84,85,86,
      87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,
      0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
      17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
      24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
      38,39,40,41,42,43,44,
      45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
      52,53,54,55,56,57,58,
      59,60,61,62,63,64,65,
      66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
      73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
      80,81,82,83,84,85,86,
      87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,
      0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
      17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
      24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
      38,39,40,41,42,43,44,
      45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
      52,53,54,55,56,57,58,
      59,60,61,62,63,64,65,
      66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
      73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
      80,81,82,83,84,85,86,
      87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,
      0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
      17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
      24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
      38,39,40,41,42,43,44,
      45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
      52,53,54,55,56,57,58,
      59,60,61,62,63,64,65,
      66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
      73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
      80,81,82,83,84,85,86,
      87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,
      0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
      17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
      24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
      38,39,40,41,42,43,44,
      45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
      52,53,54,55,56,57,58,
      59,60,61,62,63,64,65,
      66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
      73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
      80,81,82,83,84,85,86,
      87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,
      0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
      17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
      24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
      38,39,40,41,42,43,44,
      45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
      52,53,54,55,56,57,58,
      59,60,61,62,63,64,65,
      66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
      73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
      80,81,82,83,84,85,86,
      87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94
      ]
'''''
#right wheel track Dmeter

'''''
ys = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,
      2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    2,2,2,2,2,

    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
    4,4,4,4,4,
    
      ]
'''


'''''
zs = [
        #right D-meter
      0.725/12,0.057833333,0.045,0.036666667,0.031916667,0.029083333,0.0295,0.0315,0.025166667,
      0.025083333,0.027166667,0.03,0.036833333,0.041083333,0.050166667,0.060416667,0.058416667,0.054833333,
      0.053916667,0.049666667,0.0415,0.030083333,0.023083333,0.017416667,0.015666667,0.0125,0.014166667,
      0.014333333,0.01525,0.018583333,0.006833333,0.001083333,-0.006833333,-0.012166667,-0.016416667,-0.019166667,
     -0.015916667,-0.01475,-0.008916667,-0.012083333,-0.013083333,-0.012333333,-0.002916667,0.007166667,0.003416667,
     -0.00475,-0.009,-0.01175,-0.013166667,-0.013583333,-0.01175,-0.011833333,-0.009333333,-0.008166667,
     -0.005,-0.004416667,-0.004916667,-0.005833333,-0.014416667,-0.019666667,-0.020916667,-0.02475,-0.02675,
     -0.027,-0.026916667,-0.027333333,-0.0255,-0.026,-0.02025,-0.014833333,-0.0095,-0.004916667,
     -0.014916667, -0.024166667,-0.027666667,-0.029916667,-0.029833333,-0.029,-0.0255,-0.020166667,-0.013,
     -0.012083333,-0.00775,-0.002416667,0.004666667,0.014,0.003166667,-0.008166667,-0.0175,-0.0275,
     -0.0305,-0.031333333,-0.02925,-0.02625,-.295/12,
     
     #right Face
     
     0.0579166666666667,0.0554166666666667,0.0426666666666667,0.0344166666666667,0.02975,0.0269166666666667,0.0274166666666667,0.0295,0.02325,
     0.02325,0.0254166666666667,0.0283333333333333,0.03525,0.0395833333333333,0.0486666666666667,0.059,0.0570833333333333,0.0535833333333333,
     0.05275,0.0485833333333333,0.0405,0.0291666666666667,0.0221666666666667,0.0165833333333333,0.0149166666666667,0.0118333333333333,0.0135833333333333,
     0.0138333333333333,0.0148333333333333,0.01825,0.00658333333333333,0.000833333333333333,-0.007,-0.01225,-0.0164166666666667,-0.0190833333333333,
    -0.01575,-0.0145,-0.00858333333333333,-0.01175,-0.0126666666666667,-0.0118333333333333,-0.00233333333333333,0.00783333333333333,0.00416666666666667,
    -0.00391666666666667,-0.00808333333333333,-0.01075,-0.0121666666666667,-0.0125,-0.0105833333333333,-0.0105833333333333,-0.008,-0.00675,
    -0.0035,-0.00283333333333333,-0.00333333333333333,-0.00416666666666667,-0.0126666666666667,-0.0178333333333333,-0.019,-0.02275,-0.0246666666666667,
    -0.0248333333333333,-0.0246666666666667,-0.0250833333333333,-0.0231666666666667,-0.0235833333333333,-0.01775,-0.01225,-0.00683333333333333,-0.00216666666666667,
    -0.0120833333333333,-0.0213333333333333,-0.02475,-0.0269166666666667,-0.02675,-0.0258333333333333,-0.02225,-0.0168333333333333,-0.00958333333333333,
    -0.00858333333333333,-0.00425,0.00116666666666667,0.00833333333333333,0.01775,0.007,-0.00425,-0.0135,-0.0234166666666667,
    -0.0264166666666667,-0.0271666666666667,-0.025,-0.0219166666666667,-0.0201666666666667,
    
    
    #center D-meter
    0.0571666666666667,0.0601666666666667,0.0479166666666667,0.0368333333333333,0.0284166666666667,0.0235,0.02125,0.0229166666666667,0.0235,    
    0.0236666666666667,0.0280833333333333,0.0325,0.0340833333333333,0.0398333333333333, 0.0494166666666667,0.057,0.056,0.0559166666666667,  
    0.0525833333333333,0.0468333333333333,0.0389166666666667,0.02725,0.0179166666666667,0.0118333333333333,0.012,0.0105833333333333,0.0119166666666667, 
    0.0150833333333333,0.0200833333333333,0.0205,0.00858333333333333,8.33333333333333E-05,-0.00558333333333333,-0.01125,-0.01625,-0.0189166666666667,
    -0.0180833333333333,-0.01675,-0.0119166666666667,-0.0116666666666667,-0.0101666666666667,-0.00941666666666667,-0.00425,0.000833333333333333,-0.0025,    
    -0.00616666666666667,-0.00991666666666667,-0.00958333333333333,-0.01075,-0.0119166666666667,-0.0115833333333333,-0.013,-0.0116666666666667,-0.01,   
    -0.006,-0.00791666666666667,-0.00875,-0.0085,-0.0170833333333333,-0.02,-0.0201666666666667,-0.0225833333333333,-0.0225833333333333, 
    -0.02525,-0.02325,-0.02375,-0.0228333333333333,-0.0221666666666667,-0.0185833333333333,-0.0153333333333333,-0.00925,-0.00791666666666667,   
    -0.0204166666666667,-0.02925,-0.0326666666666667,-0.03575,-0.034,-0.0305833333333333,-0.0243333333333333,-0.0201666666666667,-0.0144166666666667,   
    -0.0105,-0.00658333333333333,-0.00133333333333333,0.00675,0.0139166666666667,   0.001,  -0.011, -0.023, -0.0318333333333333,    
    -0.0346666666666667,-0.0375,-0.0331666666666667,-0.027,-0.0233333333333333,
    
    #Face Center
    0.053,0.0560833333333333,0.0439166666666667,0.0328333333333333,0.0245,0.0196666666666667,0.0174166666666667,0.0191666666666667,0.0198333333333333,  
    0.02,0.0245,0.029,0.0306666666666667,0.0364166666666667,0.0460833333333333,0.05375,0.05275,0.05275, 
    0.0495,0.04375,0.0359166666666667,0.0243333333333333,0.015,0.009,0.00925,0.00783333333333333,0.00925,   
    0.0125,0.0175833333333333,0.018,0.00616666666666667,-0.00225,-0.00791666666666667,-0.0135,-0.0184166666666667,-0.0210833333333333,  
    -0.0201666666666667,-0.01875,-0.0139166666666667,-0.0135833333333333,-0.012,-0.01125,-0.006,-0.000833333333333333,-0.00416666666666667,
    -0.00775,-0.0114166666666667,-0.011,-0.0121666666666667,-0.01325,-0.0128333333333333,-0.01425,-0.0128333333333333,-0.0110833333333333,  
    -0.00708333333333333,-0.00891666666666667,-0.00966666666666667,-0.00941666666666667,-0.0179166666666667,-0.02075,-0.0209166666666667,-0.02325,-0.0231666666666667,
    -0.02575,-0.02375,-0.0241666666666667,-0.0231666666666667,-0.0225,-0.0188333333333333,-0.0155,-0.00941666666666667,-0.008,  
    -0.0204166666666667,-0.02925,-0.0325833333333333,-0.0355833333333333,-0.0338333333333333,-0.0303333333333333,-0.024,-0.0198333333333333,-0.014, 
    -0.01,-0.006,-0.00075,0.00741666666666667,0.0146666666666667,0.00175,-0.0101666666666667,-0.0220833333333333,-0.0309166666666667,   
    -0.0336666666666667,-0.0364166666666667,-0.0320833333333333,-0.0258333333333333,-0.0220833333333333,
    
    #Left D-Meter
    0.048166667,0.053,0.047583333,0.034333333,0.025666667,0.019416667,0.02025,0.01625,0.017333333,
    0.0195,0.017166667,0.01575,0.015833333,0.02075,0.02825,0.039583333,0.046583333,0.04425,
    0.0415,0.036,0.032833333,0.023,0.011083333,0.006166667,0.007083333,0.006916667,0.008833333,
    0.014333333,0.01675,0.018166667,0.008666667,-0.002916667,-0.013166667,-0.014833333,-0.01925,-0.0215,
    -0.025416667,-0.023333333,-0.019666667,-0.012916667,-0.0145,-0.015416667,-0.012916667,-0.008416667,-0.005,
    -0.005583333,-0.005,-0.007583333,-0.011833333,-0.012666667,-0.010666667,-0.010166667,-0.0095,-0.009083333,
    -0.00975,-0.007666667,-0.009833333,-0.01,-0.014416667,-0.01825,-0.019,-0.018416667,-0.02,
    -0.0225,-0.022583333,-0.022833333,-0.019083333,-0.016333333,-0.014333333,-0.009,-0.00475,0.000416667,
    -0.0055,-0.020583333,-0.028,-0.032083333,-0.029166667,-0.027,-0.024416667,-0.021666667,-0.017166667,
    -0.013,-0.009,-0.008333333,-0.000916667,0.00975,0.009833333,-0.001166667,-0.0115,-0.025083333,
    -0.033833333,-0.037166667,-0.0335,-0.02725,-0.021916667,
    
    #Face Left
    
    0.0530833333333333,0.0578333333333333,0.0523333333333333,0.039,0.03025,0.0239166666666667,0.0246666666666667,0.0205833333333333,0.0215833333333333, 
    0.02375,0.0213333333333333,0.0198333333333333,0.0198333333333333,0.0246666666666667,0.0320833333333333,0.0433333333333333,0.05025,0.0479166666666667,   
    0.0450833333333333,0.0395,0.03625,0.0263333333333333,0.0143333333333333,0.00933333333333333,0.0101666666666667,0.00991666666666667,0.0118333333333333,  
    0.01725,0.0195833333333333,0.0209166666666667,0.0113333333333333,-0.000333333333333333,-0.0106666666666667,-0.0124166666666667,-0.0168333333333333,-0.0191666666666667, 
    -0.0231666666666667,-0.0211666666666667,-0.0175833333333333,-0.0109166666666667,-0.0125833333333333,-0.0135833333333333,-0.0111666666666667,-0.00666666666666667,-0.00333333333333333,  
    -0.004,-0.0035,-0.00616666666666667,-0.0105,-0.0114166666666667,-0.0095,-0.009,-0.00841666666666667,-0.00808333333333333,
    -0.00883333333333333,-0.00683333333333333,-0.00908333333333333,-0.00933333333333333,-0.0138333333333333,-0.01775,-0.0185,-0.018,-0.0196666666666667,    
    -0.02225,-0.0224166666666667,-0.02275,-0.0190833333333333,-0.0164166666666667,-0.0144166666666667,-0.00916666666666667,-0.005,-8.33333333333333E-05,    
    -0.00591666666666667,-0.0210833333333333,-0.0285833333333333,-0.03275,-0.0299166666666667,-0.02775,-0.02525,-0.0225833333333333,-0.0181666666666667,    
    -0.0140833333333333,-0.0101666666666667,-0.00958333333333333,-0.00225,0.00833333333333333,0.00841666666666667,-0.00266666666666667,-0.0130833333333333,-0.02675,    
    -0.0355833333333333,-0.039,-0.0354166666666667,-0.02925,-0.0239166666666667
    
    ]

'''


     
     
# plot raw data
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, color='b')

 #do fit
tmp_A = []
tmp_b = []
for i in range(len(xs)):
    tmp_A.append([xs[i], ys[i], 1])
    tmp_b.append(zs[i])
b = np.matrix(tmp_b).T
A = np.matrix(tmp_A)

 #Or use Scipy
from scipy.linalg import lstsq
fit, residual, rnk, errors = lstsq(A, b)

print("solution: %f x + %f y + %f = z" % (fit[0], fit[1], fit[2]))
print("errors: \n", errors)
print("residual:", residual)

# plot plane
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xlim[0], xlim[1]),
                  np.arange(ylim[0], ylim[1]))
Z = np.zeros(X.shape)
for r in range(X.shape[0]):
    for c in range(X.shape[1]):
        Z[r,c] = fit[0] * X[r,c] + fit[1] * Y[r,c] + fit[2]
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z, color='k')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to approximate you 3D points, not only using a plane, but a generic quadratic surface and getting the equation as well, you can take a look at [this library](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6). Below an example, you should be able to easily adapt the example to your points. I am taking the example from [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72320274/how-to-fit-a-curved-surface-to-a-set-of-data-points-and-obtain-the-equation-for/72644449#72644449) (it's neither accepted nor upvoted, I wanted to suggest it as a duplicate).
The `C` array consists of the equation coefficients.

In the section `# some 3-dim points` just replace `data` with your data.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some 3-dim points
mean = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
cov = np.array([[1.0,-0.5,0.8], [-0.5,1.1,0.0], [0.8,0.0,1.0]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 50)

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5), np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()


# best-fit quadratic curve
A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,:2], np.prod(data[:,:2], axis=1), data[:,:2]**2]
C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])

# evaluate it on a grid
Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX*YY, XX**2, YY**2], C).reshape(X.shape)

# plot points and fitted surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('auto')
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

As a side note, you can easily compute the best fit plane using the [scikit-spatial](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. [Here](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gallery/fitting/plot_plane.html#sphx-glr-gallery-fitting-plot-plane-py) is an example to compute the best-fit plane.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I am having trouble understanding how to use my own data. For example I tried this                                                                             
data = [0,0,725],[1,0,695],[2,0,484]

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5), np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()


# best-fit quadratic curve
A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,:2], np.prod(data[:,:2], axis=1), data[:,:2]**2]
C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])

Comment: Provide the actual data, or part of it, not an image, please.

Comment: Also could you show an example of how you get the equation from C exactly?

Comment: `C` is just an array with the coefficients of the quadratic equation.

Comment: I'm pretty new to posting on this website sorry. How can I send you the code in a good format?

Comment: Just paste into the code a small 2D numpy array with the coordinates just as an example. Those `xs`... arrays are very badly formatted.

Comment: Does this code work for any number of coordinates?

Comment: When I print out C i get this: [ 5.42420078e-02 -1.87830407e-03 -1.55918635e-04  3.92301817e-05 1.18839188e-05 -6.23674538e-04]. What equation is this for?

Comment: What do you mean? N-D coordinates?
The coefficients are `a*X**2 + b*Y**2 + ...` etc

Comment: Z = C[4]*X**2. + C[5]*Y**2. + C[3]*X*Y + C[1]*X + C[2]*Y + C[0] like this?

Comment: c[6]x^3 + c[9]y^3 + c[7]x^2 y + c[8] x y^2 + c[3] x^2 + c[5] y^2 + c[4] xy + c[1]x + c[2] y + c[0] would this be used for cubic?

Comment: The code I have provided it's just for second order and only 3D points.