# How to generate a 3D surface function to fit given 3D points and interpolate 3rd coordinate if I have other 3 coordinates

Tags: python, linear-regression, interpolation, curve-fitting

I am a beginer in Python.

I have some 3D point data as below,

```
x= [600, 450, 302, 151, 600, 450, 302, 151, 599, 450, 302, 150, 599, 449, 301, 150]
y= [0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 2.1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4.1, 4, 4.1, 6.1, 6.1, 6, 6]
z =[23.77, 17.74, 11.93,5.97, 23.60, 17.60, 11.78, 5.82, 23.09, 17.24, 11.39, 5.39, 21.89, 16.18, 10.36, 4.26]
```

I want to fit a surface to these points and then create a function of this surface such that if I want to plot a new point on this surface and I have two coordinates (x, y) of it then I should be able to find the z coordinate of the it.

Could someone please assist me, how can I proceed with this problem?

I tried using `scipy.linalg.lstsq` function to fit quadratic curve, but I am not getting any output.

I am simply expecting a plot and a surface equation which can give me the value of Z if i have X, and Y.

Comment: To be more precise, I am expecting a regression model for it.

Comment: Given those points i think that there are infinite surfaces possible. 
Same with respect to the point you want to search in them: given a x, y one can have more than one z fitting the surface equation.
Just think, as an example, of a surface with multiple convexity/concavity and a x, y plan touching every convexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define a best-fit plane without implementing the math from zero, you can use the [`scikit-spatial`](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/Plane/methods/skspatial.objects.Plane.best_fit.html#skspatial.objects.Plane.best_fit) library in the following way (as explained in the example).

Install the library (for instance using `pip`, but you can also use `conda`)

```bash
pip install scikit-spatial
```

Import the library:

```py
from skspatial.objects import Plane
```

Define your points:

```py
points = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Compute the best-fit plane:

```py
plane = Plane.best_fit(points)
```

You can also plot the plane using the [`plot_3d`](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/Plane/methods/skspatial.objects.Plane.plot_3d.html#skspatial.objects.Plane.plot_3d) method.

Moreover, you can get the plane's coefficients using the [`cartesian`](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/Plane/methods/skspatial.objects.Plane.cartesian.html#skspatial.objects.Plane.cartesian) method:

```py
coefficients = plane.cartesian()
```

The coefficients are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` and the plane equation is `ax + by + cz + d = 0`. Thus, given the `x` and `y` coordinates, then you can compute the `z` coordinate as follows:

```py
x = 3
y = 4
z = -(a*x + b*y + d) / c
print(z)
```

Finally, if you need to fit a quadratic surface, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644449/14952856) of mine (unfortunately, it's neither accepted nor upvoted, so I cannot suggest it as a duplicate).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I am sorry but As I said I am beginer in python, I don't know how to these plane coefficients to get the value of z. Could you please kindly elaborate that?

Answer (score -1):

If you have no clue for an equation model try several equations until you obtain an acceptable result.

Linear regression with the equation of plane :

[image]

Linear regression with equation of quadratic surface :

[image]

RLMSE : Root Least Mean Square Error.

Note : From the above result and because A and C are very small one can expect an almost as good result with the only four parameters (instead of six) equation of quadratique surface : z = B y^2 + D x + E y + F .

[image]

Details of the calculus :

[image]

Comment: Can't I create a model for the above calculations? or a regression model to fit a best fitting plane instead of a surface?

Comment: Also did you do these above calculations in python?

Comment: The regression model to fit a best fitting plane is given in my answer : z = a x +b y +c . Of course all the above calculations can be done with python. But this is taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. The three above numerical calculus are elementary linear regression.

Comment: If you don't mind, Could you please share the method, how did you do the calculations?

Comment: Don't you know "Least squares fitting" ? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html ?

Comment: See at the end of the answer. The calculus is shown in details.

Comment: Don't mention it. My answer was to help you to find an equation model. Coding it in a software is up to you.